# Finding the critical point of this function and not getting expected answer.

Tags: calculus, radicals

I'm trying to find the critical point for f(x)=2x^2-1000*sqrt(x). However, I do already know the answer, but I have no idea how it is the answer. I've tried to work it out multiple times, but I keep going in the same loop. Here's my work on paper: http://puu.sh/BXjHY/dc18f00104.jpg

At the end of my work, when I'm faced with 125 = x^(3/2), I get an answer above a thousand, yet if i were to flip the exponential fraction so that the equation would then be 125 = x^(2/3), I get 25. I can't figure out where that x^(2/3) would come from!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The only real solution to $125=x^{3/2}$ is $x=25$.  The only real solution to $125=x^{2/3}$ is $x=625\times \sqrt 5$.

Comment: So by the sound of it, I'm inputting things into my calculator backwards? I thought x^(3/2) would be input as sqrt(x^3) into a calculator

Comment: That ought to work.  If $x=25=5^2$, then $\sqrt {x^3}=\sqrt {5^6}=5^3=125$ as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$125 = x^{3/2} \implies 125^{2/3} = x^{(3/2)(2/3)} =x$$

That is $$x= 125 ^{2/3} = 5^2 = 25 $$

Comment: Ahh thank you! This clears it up perfectly!

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Cheer